# How to allow controllable data races in C++ without getting UB

Tags: c++, concurrency, data-race

While implementing the transactional memory algorithm [TL2](https://people.csail.mit.edu/shanir/publications/Transactional_Locking.pdf), we noticed that it allows data races: while committing the write transaction, a reading transaction can read the same memory region.

However, the invalid read will be further invalidated because the version of the lock will be updated after a successful write. Therefore, we will not use the invalid read result and the transaction will be aborted.

Data races in C++ causes Undefined Behavior. Is there a way to tell the compiler that data races are OK so formally we don't have any UB in our program?

One possible solution would be allocating the transactional memory like a bunch of `std::atomic`:

```cpp
auto memory_region = new std::atomic<char>[size];
```

and work with memory using atomic operations with `std::memory_order_relaxed`.

However, I was wondering if there is another more elegant solution, that doesn't provide any overhead.

Comment: I wouldn't go for atomic. One option if you have more readers than writers is to use reader-writer locks (see std::shared_lock). There is also the "lock-free programming" (which I didn't do much with tbh). In the end there is no free lunch when you need to synchronize between threads and the best solution will depend on the nature of your data and algorithms. (And often requires profiling to find the real bottlencks in your system)

Comment: @PepijnKramer The thing is we don't need to synchronize the threads, we want to allow the datarace without causing a _formal_ UB.

Comment: there isn't a way to turn off a data race being UB.  It has to be UB as that is the nature of a data race, you can't know what results you'll get.

Comment: Dataraces will be dataraces if you call them UB or not they still will result in unpredictable output (even if the program will continue without crashing). So I really doubt this is what you want. Increasing performance at the cost of reliability is a no go area for me

Comment: Data races are awesome and should not be feared. Race more, win more.

Comment: @NathanOliver I agree, but we we know that concurrent read and write is okay because the algorithm guarantees that we are not going to use the invalid read result. UB is too broad, it can mean that "false" becomes "true" all of the sudden. We want to either squeeze the possible undefined behaviours or guarantee their absence

Comment: @PepijnKramer The algorithm itself is reliable, please read the question carefully before writing the comments. It guarantees that it will not use invalid read if the datarace happens. However, the language memory model says that it will be a complete UB if a program has a data race. We want to access a memory region concurrently because we know what we are doing, but at the same time have a formal guarantee that nothing will break (practically nothing will break, but can we achieve this formally)

Comment: @PepijnKramer, Imagine two threads. A locks a mutex, updates a variable, and releases the mutex. B locks the samed mutex, reads the same variable, and then unlocks. If the threads do their thing concurrently, then that's a "data race." We cannot predict whether B will see the original value or the updated value. But it is _not_ UB. If it were UB, then the language spec would allow literally _anything_ to happen, but in this case, the spec allows only those two very specific outcomes. In _some_ instance, a data race like that can be benign--either outcome is acceptable.

Comment: @SolomonSlow That's not a _data race_ in the definition of the standard. I see the term _race condition_ used to distinguish this benign form from the standard's form that is _always_ UB.

Comment: @user17732522, and I have seen the exact opposite of that in print. ...where the author says, "race condition" to mean a defect in the program or a fault condition, and, "data race" to describe the benign case. Go figure!